# can not access a member of class org.springframework.data.jpa.util.HibernateProxyDetector with modifiers

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, multi-tenant

I am implementing multi-tenant feature in our project ( Spring MVC and hibernate ) by following [this tutorial](https://sunitkatkar.blogspot.com/2018/05/adding-tenants-without-application.html) 
but it is not working

the concept is when application initialize get the tenant details from Master DB like url,usernames password and using this we create tenant datasource. When the application run it gives the below error

**Error**

```
SEVERE: Servlet [SpringDispatcher] in web application [/####] threw load() exception
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader can not access a member of class org.springframework.data.jpa.util.HibernateProxyDetector with modifiers ""
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:102)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:436)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.instantiateFactory(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:135)
    at org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader.loadFactories(SpringFactoriesLoader.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ProxyUtils.<clinit>(ProxyUtils.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<init>(ClassTypeInformation.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.util.ClassTypeInformation.<clinit>(ClassTypeInformation.java:45)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.<init>(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:58)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.DefaultRepositoryMetadata.<init>(DefaultRepositoryMetadata.java:52)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.getMetadata(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:73)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.getRepositoryConfigurations(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:99)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.registerRepositoriesIn(RepositoryConfigurationDelegate.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:85)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:344)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:151)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:124)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:318)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:239)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:606)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:983)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4829)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1425)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1415)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:941)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:671)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:353)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:493)
```

**ApplicationContextConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.e*****e","com.*****re","com.db.master"})
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource({"classpath:db.properties", "classpath:log4j.properties", "classpath:fee2CommonProperties.properties", "classpath:examinations.properties", "classpath:security.properties",
    "classpath:build.properties","classpath:commonProperties.properties","classpath:toaster.properties","classpath:screenReference.properties","classpath:socialLogin.properties"})
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Import({ WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.class, WebSocketSecurityMessageBrokerConfigurer.class})
public class ApplicationContextConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean(name = "viewResolver")
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(getHandlerInterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    Interceptor getHandlerInterceptor() {
        return new Interceptor();
    }
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Profile("Test")
    public DataSource getDataSourceTest() {
        System.out.println("test loaded");
        BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3308/dbapi?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername("admin");
        dataSource.setPassword("admin");
        
        return dataSource;
        /*return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
            .setName("testdb;MODE=MySQL;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false")
            .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2)
            .build();*/
    }

    @Bean
    public DozerBeanMapper beanMapper() {
        final DozerBeanMapper mapper = new DozerBeanMapper();
        return mapper;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/svg/**").addResourceLocations("/nxqLiteParent/svg/");
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
        CommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultEncoding("utf-8");
        return resolver;
    }
    

    
    @Autowired
    private RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initCustomMessageConverter() {
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = adapter.getMessageConverters();
        BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter imageConverter = new BufferedImageHttpMessageConverter();;
        messageConverters.add(0,imageConverter);
    }

}
```

**TenantDatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement


@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = {"com.ed***re.dao","com.ed***re.fee.dao","com.ed***re.rest.dao"},
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "tenantEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "tenantTransactionManager"
)
public class TenantDatabaseConfig {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TenantDatabaseConfig.class);


    @Bean(name = "tenantTransactionManager")
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(@Qualifier("tenantEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory tenantEntityManager) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(tenantEntityManager);
        return transactionManager;
    }



    @Bean(name = "datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider")
    public MultiTenantConnectionProvider multiTenantConnectionProvider() {
        return new DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl();
    }



    @Bean(name = "currentTenantIdentifierResolver")
    public CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver currentTenantIdentifierResolver() {
        return new CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl();
    }

    
    @Autowired
    @Bean(name = "tenantEntityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(
            @Qualifier("datasourceBasedMultitenantConnectionProvider") MultiTenantConnectionProvider connectionProvider,
            @Qualifier("currentTenantIdentifierResolver") CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver tenantResolver) {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfBean.setPackagesToScan("com.testpro.model", "com.testpro.fee.model", "com.testpro.rest.model");
        emfBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, connectionProvider);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, tenantResolver);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "none");
        emfBean.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        LOG.info("tenantEntityManagerFactory set up successfully!");
        return emfBean;
    }
    
    @Bean
      public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.testpro.model", "com.testpro.fee.model", "com.testpro.rest.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
      }
    

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT, "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, false);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "false");
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", true);
        properties.put("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory");
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT, MultiTenancyStrategy.DATABASE);
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_CONNECTION_PROVIDER, multiTenantConnectionProvider());
        properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.MULTI_TENANT_IDENTIFIER_RESOLVER, currentTenantIdentifierResolver());
        return properties;
    }
}
```

**MasterDatabaseConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.db.master.master.repository",
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "masterEntityManagerFactory",
        transactionManagerRef = "masterTransactionManager"
)
public class MasterDatabaseConfig {
    
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterDatabaseConfig.class);


    @Bean(name = "masterDataSource")
    public DataSource masterDataSource() {

        LOG.info("Setting up masterDataSource with#############: ");

        HikariDataSource ds = new HikariDataSource();

        ds.setUsername("root");
        ds.setPassword("root");
        ds.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db14?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8");
        ds.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        ds.setPoolName("Master");

        // HikariCP settings
        // Maximum number of actual connection in the pool
        ds.setMaximumPoolSize(10);

        // Minimum number of idle connections in the pool
        ds.setMinimumIdle(10);

        // Maximum waiting time for a connection from the pool
        ds.setConnectionTimeout(20000);

        // Maximum time that a connection is allowed to sit idle in the pool
        ds.setIdleTimeout(300000);
        LOG.info("Setup of masterDataSource succeeded.");
        return ds;
    }




    
       @Bean
        public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
            HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
        }
     
        /*
         * Here you can specify any provider specific properties.
         */
       private Properties hibernateProperties() {
            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.DIALECT,
                    "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
            properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.SHOW_SQL, true);
            properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.FORMAT_SQL, true);
            properties.put(org.hibernate.cfg.Environment.HBM2DDL_AUTO, "update");
            return properties;
        }
       
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "masterEntityManagerFactory")
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean masterEntityManagerFactory() {
            LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

            // Set the master data source
            em.setDataSource(masterDataSource());

            // The master tenant entity and repository need to be scanned
            em.setPackagesToScan(
                    new String[] { MasterTenant.class.getPackage().getName(),
                            MasterDAO.class.getPackage().getName() });
            // Setting a name for the persistence unit as Spring sets it as
            // 'default' if not defined
            em.setPersistenceUnitName("masterdb-persistence-unit");

            // Setting Hibernate as the JPA provider
            JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
            em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

            // Set the hibernate properties
            em.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
            LOG.info("Setup of masterEntityManagerFactory succeeded.");
            return em;
        }
       
        @Autowired
        @Primary
        @Bean(name = "masterTransactionManager")
        public JpaTransactionManager masterTransactionManager(
                @Qualifier("masterEntityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
            return transactionManager;
        }
     
        @Bean
        @Autowired
        public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
            JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
            txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
            return txManager;
        }

    
    

}
```

**DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.java**

```
public class DataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl
        extends AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Injected MasterTenantRepository to access the tenant information from the
     * master_tenant table
     */
    @Autowired
    private MasterDAO masterDAO;


     
    private Map<String, DataSource> dataSourcesMtApp = new TreeMap<>();

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectAnyDataSource() {
        // This method is called more than once. So check if the data source map
        // is empty. If it is then rescan master_tenant table for all tenant
        // entries.
        //System.out.println("Select any datasource");
        if (dataSourcesMtApp.isEmpty()) {
            //System.out.println("dataSourcesMtApp.isEmpty()");
            
            
            
            List<MasterTenant> masterTenants = masterDAO.findAll();

            for (MasterTenant masterTenant : masterTenants) {
                dataSourcesMtApp.put(masterTenant.getTenantId(),
                        DataSourceUtil.createAndConfigureDataSource(masterTenant));
            }
        }
        return this.dataSourcesMtApp.values().iterator().next();
    }

    @Override
    protected DataSource selectDataSource(String tenantIdentifier) {
        // If the requested tenant id is not present check for it in the master
        // database 'master_tenant' table
        //System.out.println("Select DataSource");
        if (!this.dataSourcesMtApp.containsKey(tenantIdentifier)) {
            //System.out.println("Select DataSource not contain key");
            List<MasterTenant> masterTenants = masterDAO.findAll();
            
            for (MasterTenant masterTenant : masterTenants) {
                dataSourcesMtApp.put(masterTenant.getTenantId(),
                        DataSourceUtil.createAndConfigureDataSource(masterTenant));
            }
        }
        return this.dataSourcesMtApp.get(tenantIdentifier);
    }


}
```

**MasterDAO.jajva**

```
@Repository
public interface MasterDAO extends JpaRepository<MasterTenant, Integer>   {

      @Override
        public List<MasterTenant> findAll();

}
```

Comment: Where is your `MasterDAO`? do you register it in the Spring Context? do you have a `@Component` annotation on top of it?

Comment: Error is changed now